# How do I use the apache httpClient API to send file + api key and other parameters as a single request?

Tags: java, apache, api, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have started to test http client apache API. I need it because I would like to send requests and to receive responses to virustotal API. Virus total API requires to parameters in the post request:

1. the api key value (a unique value for each user)
2. the file itself as I understood from their website.

For example:

```
>>> url = "https://www.virustotal.com/vtapi/v2/url/scan"
>>> parameters = {"url": "http://www.virustotal.com",
...               "apikey": "-- YOUR API KEY --"}
>>> data = urllib.urlencode(parameters)
>>> req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
```

At the moment, I am trying to do the same thing in Java instead of Python. Here is a part of my source code commented to guide throughout the steps:

```
  CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
  //create post request
  HttpPost request = new HttpPost("https://www.virustotal.com/vtapi/v2/file/scan");
  //http json header
  request.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");

  String str  = gson.toJson(param);

  String fileName = UUID.randomUUID().toString() + ".txt";

  try {
    //API key
    StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(str);
    Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileName));
    writer.write(VirusDefinitionTest.malware());
    request.setEntity(entity);
  } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
  FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(new File(fileName)); 

  builder.addTextBody("my_file", fileName);
  HttpEntity entity = builder.build();
  request.setEntity(entity);

  HttpResponse response;
  try {
    response = httpClient.execute(request);
```

...

Unfortunately, I receive HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden. Obviously, the error is somewhere in the entities but I cannot find how to do it. Any help would be deeply welcomed.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me with Apache 4.5.2 HttpClient:

```
CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
try {
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://www.virustotal.com/vtapi/v2/file/scan");

    FileBody bin = new FileBody(new File("... the file here ..."));
    // the API key here
    StringBody comment = new StringBody("5ec8de.....", ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN);

    HttpEntity reqEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
            .addPart("apikey", comment)
            .addPart("file", bin)
            .build();

    httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);

    System.out.println("executing request " + httppost.getRequestLine());
    CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    try {
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
        System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
        HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
        if (resEntity != null) {
            System.out.println("ToString:" + EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));
        }
        EntityUtils.consume(resEntity);
    } finally {
        response.close();
    }
} finally {
    httpclient.close();
}
```

The important part was the `reqEntity` which had to have two specifically named fields, `"apikey"`, and `"file"`. Running this with a valid API key gives me the expected response from the [API](https://www.virustotal.com/en/documentation/public-api/#getting-started).

Comment: This all works great for VirusTotal with Java. The `EntityUtils.toString(resEntity)` was the last piece of the puzzle.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that first you add explicit "content-type" header which is "application/json" and at the end you send the Muiltipart entity. You need to add all the parameters and the file to the Muiltipart entity. Now the parameters are not send, because they are overwritten by Muiltipart entity:

```
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
//create post request
HttpPost request = new HttpPost("https://www.virustotal.com/vtapi/v2/file/scan");
//http json header
request.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");

String str  = gson.toJson(param);

String fileName = UUID.randomUUID().toString() + ".txt";

try {
//API key
StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(str);
Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileName));
writer.write(VirusDefinitionTest.malware());
// --> You set parameters here !!!
request.setEntity(entity);
} catch (IOException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
}
MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(new File(fileName)); 

builder.addTextBody("my_file", fileName);
HttpEntity entity = builder.build();
// --> You overwrite the parameters here !!!
request.setEntity(entity);

HttpResponse response;
try {
 response = httpClient.execute(request);
```